# Eclipse debugger shows Hibernate-managed object has not been lazily-initialized

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I gather that Hibernate uses the javassist library to handle lazy initialization of objects. Say I have the following entities (getters/setters/annotations are truncated):

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {
    private ComponentEntity comp;
}

@Entity
public class ComponentEntity {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Now I call the following method:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
    MainEntity main = this.dao.find(1);

    // Case A
    main.getComp().getName();
    // Case B
    String localVariableName = main.getComp().getName();
}
```

When the DAO retrieves main, the `comp` object is not yet initialized due to lazy initialization. I expect that after calling `Case A`, the `comp` object will have been retrieved from the database, but based on the debugger, all the comp object properties appear as null.

It's only when after `Case B` where I save the `name` value into a `localVariableName` that I can see localVariableName get a non-null value.

Why is Eclipse showing my object properties as null?

Comment: This might help http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html

Comment: Your diagnostic is wrong. A and B are exactly the same thing. Whether you store the result or not in a local variable is irrelevant. So if A doen't throw an exception, B won't. Since everything is in a transactional method, you shouldn't have any exception.

Comment: It actually doesn't throw an exception, but the entire object's properties are initialized to null during Case A. On Case B, that's the time they are populated with the values from the database. I'll update the post to make this clear.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry you're correct. I've been looking at the Eclipse debugger wrongly. Will update the question and answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hibernate-managed objects that are lazily-initialized are managed by javassist proxy objects. Therefore in the Eclipse debugger, you have to know where to look.

[image: screenshot of null proxy object with handler.initialized set to false]

The `offer` object is a proxy object that contains a handler object which contains a flag called `initialized`. It's currently set to `false`.

[image: screenshot of proxy object with null props but with hander.initialized set to true and handler.target containing the initialized actual object]

After `Case A`, the handler's `initialized` flag is now set to `true`. The `handler.target` object also changes to reflect the actual `offer` object's initialized properties.

So the lazy initialization is working as intended.